# Add additional box-shadow to an element where existing shadow is unknown

Tags: css

I'm assuming the answer to this question is that it's impossible, but I'm asking anyway in the hopes that someone knows of a clever workaround.

Let's say I have the following class `.left-inset` that adds a 1px white box-shadow to the left of an element to give it some depth:

```
.left-inset {
  box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.25);
}
```

The problem is that if the element I add this class to already has a box-shadow defined, this box-shadow will override that existing one (or this shadow won't be applied depending on the cascade). I want to find a way to safely add this class without conflicts.

I'm hoping there is some future browser support for something like the following:

```
.left-inset {
  box-shadow: inherit, inherit, inherit, inset 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.25);
}
```

Inherit isn't the right word here, because inherit implies the value from the parent, but you get the idea.

This method, while not full-proof, would at least allow me to know that I'm not conflicting with existing box-shadows unless they define more than three. In most cases, this will be good enough.

Does anyone know whether anything like this is possible, or whether there is a proposed syntax for adding additional shadows to already defined ones?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An absolutely positioned pseudo-element (with the original container having position set) seems like the only solution:

**[See the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/GP8RX/6/)** (I did different size/color for visual).

```
.test:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow:3px 3px rgba(275,0,0,.25);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not applicable to ```<select>``` elements, where no pseudo-element is supported :(

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to use a pseudo-element:

```
.left-inset::after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;

    box-shadow: 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.25);
}
```

It's a little bit hacky, but as long as the element hasn't defined the ::after pseudo-element already, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to determine the current box-shadow, superimpose the required parts to it and apply it back (not sure if it'll be worth the trouble but..).

`window.getComputedStyle(element).boxShadow`

will give you a string formatted like:

`<color> <left> <top> <softness> <spread>` - for example: `rgb(102, 102, 102) 5px 5px 5px 0px`

Once you have the above string in a variable:

1. split it using space character - `s = s.split(' ');`
2. take the last four parts
3. replace or keep individual values as required in the array
4. join the array using space - `s = s.join(' ');`
5. apply it back to the element - `elem.style.boxShadow = s;`

**NOTE**: This works in ff and chrome (since the returned string format is the same). But i think this is too much of an overkill to actually try in a production version. Moreover, it'll take even more work to superimpose styles from a class you've written in your css.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is what you want http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/

SCROLL BELOW TO FIND MULTIPLE SHADOWS.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question.