# How to "add details" to CSS (example Box shadow)

Tags: css, attributes

I'm making a navigation bar and essentially I have box-shadows on the bottom, left (first-child) and right (last-child).

My structure is `<ul><li><a><span>`

I have box-shadows on the bottom for `ul li a { 0 1px 0 0 green }`, and want to add box-shadow on the sides for the first and last element `ul li:first-child a { -1px 0 0 0 red }`. However, the box-shadow property is being overridden with the `:first-child` selector... is there a way I can say "add -1px 0 0 0 red to the previous box-shadow style".

Hope I'm making sense. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LJj2p/

Thanks!

Comment: I had to change the css3 properties so I could view on safari but I see the box shaddow and hover background still is a gradient so I'm not seeing the problem. However as an fyi li a:hover and li:first-child a have the same css rule value so any classing rules in the last one will override, even though that's not the case here.

Comment: @AlexReynolds ah yes it was another error. I've clarified my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You cannot add a `box-shadow` to something that has one, as it will overwrite it (or, more specifically, the one with the higher specificity wins). You need to define both shadows at one time for the `:first-child` / `:last-child` case.

However, using a pseudo-element [you can effectively "add" a shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486071/add-additional-box-shadow-to-an-element-where-existing-shadow-is-unknown/11486224#11486224), though it is not truly adding it.